# BD by default in Vtiger CRM 6.0.0

Tags: vtiger

I'm using [Vtiger CRM 6.0.0](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vtigercrm/files/vtiger%20CRM%206.0.0/Core%20Product/)

I have the CRM, but I do not have the BD, and I can not install a new one either.
What I need are the instructions that create the structure and data.

Does anyone know how to create the default DB without using the installation process?

Answer (score 0):

The default db is saved in the schema folder DatabaseSchema.xml

Check the file modules/Install/models/InitSchema.php to see what the installation process would do when you install for the first time vtiger